# Way to obtain full directory information in a batch

Tags: c#, system.io.file

We’ve got a process that obtains a list of files from a remote transatlantic Samba share. This is naturally on the slow side, however it’s made worse by the fact that we don’t just need the names of the files, we need the last write times to spot updates. There’s quite a lot of files in the directory, and as far as I can tell, the .NET file API insists on me asking for each one individually. Is there a faster way of obtaining the information we need?

Comment: Try something like this :             DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo("path");
            Dictionary<string, DateTime> dict = info.EnumerateFiles().GroupBy(x => x.FullName, y => y.LastWriteTime).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.FirstOrDefault());

Answer (score 1):

I would love to find a way myself. I have exactly the same problem - huge number of files on a slow network location, and I need to scan for changes.

As far as I know, you do need to ask for file properties one by one.

The amount of information transferred per file should not be high though; the roundabout request-response time is probably the main problem. You can help the situation by running multiple requests in parallel (e.g. using `Parallel.ForEach`)

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is most likely no, at least not in a meaningful way.

Exactly how you enumerate the files in your code is almost irrelevant since they all boil down to the same file system API in Windows.  Unfortunately, there is no function that returns a list of file details in one call*.

So, no matter what your code looks like, somewhere below, it's still enumerating the directory contents and calling a particular file function individually for each file.

If this is really a problem, I would look into moving the detection logic closer to the files and send your app the results periodically.

*Disclaimer: It's been a long time since I've been down this far in the stack and I'm just browsing the API docs now, there may be a new function somewhere that does exactly this.

Comment: Investigating a bit further, if you drop down to the Win32 level, you can pull the information at the same time as you enumerate, which is significantly faster, but I can't find anything that just performs a single operation in the manner I was looking for. I guess people weren't really thinking about transatlantic samba drives back when Win32 was designed.